# How to create progressive jpeg with custom interlace in php?

Tags: php, encoding

I typically create progressive jpeg with php using the following

```
$source = imagecreatetruecolor($Width,$Height);
imageinterlace($source, true);
```

But I wish to produce an image with [steep-progression](https://cloudinary.com/blog/progressive_jpegs_and_green_martians). It can be generated with a "scan-script"

```
0 1 2: 0 0 0 2;
0 1 2: 0 0 2 1;
0 1 2: 0 0 1 0;
1: 1 63 0 0;
2: 1 63 0 0;
0: 1 63 0 0;
```

But this script seems to be specific to `cjpeg`. How can I do the same or something similar from within php?

Comment: you can use cjpeg from php via exec command (prob. only ez option) or create php module from cjpeg